# Need clarification as confusion between whom or who

Tags: grammar

Covid-19 patient was telling his story, how he recovered. govt officials always trace with how many people he made contact.

The Building I was staying in was quarantined and contact tracing was done immediately I was called by hospital and govt. officials and they found out who I was in contact with, how did i go from the airport to home.

Is this correct **who I was in contact with**.?
I think it should be they found out **whom I was in contact with.**

Comment: Don't ever use _whom_. You can always use _who_ instead. Using _whom_ -- even if you have used it "correctly" -- is uncommon and distracting. It's like using _thou hast_ instead of _you have_; not a real part of Modern English speech any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either is correct.

Historically, *whom* would have been used here because it is being used as the object of the preposition *with*. Very careful speakers still use *whom* today.

But in contemporary usage, *who* is widely used for both the object and subject case.